# Being forgiven for all of your sins for going to a Bris

Tags: brit-milah, repentance-teshuvah

I heard somewhere that going to a Bris will have all of your sins forgiven because of the following story:

Hashem told Eliyahu HaNavi that he'd have to go to every Bris. Eliyahu responded, "what if the father of the baby is a sinner?"

"I'll forgive him for his sins," said Hashem.

"What if the Mohel or Sandek is a sinner?"

"I'll forgive them for their sins."

"What if the people attending are sinners?"

"I'll forgive them for there sins as well," answered Hashem.

I'm looking for a source for this story.